# Combining nested fields in a MongoDB document into an python array

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm pretty new to Python as well as MongoDB and am learning while working on my project.
In my project, I have a MongoDB document that looks something like what one has after running the following command:

```
db.materials.insertOne({
"structure": {
    "sites": [
        {
            "xyz": [
                11,
                12,
                13
            ],
        },
        {
            "xyz": [
                21,
                22,
                23
            ],
        },
        {
            "xyz": [
                31,
                32,
                33
            ],
        }
    ]
}})
```

What I want is to generate a python array that combines the 3rd element of each "xyz" list. i.e. I'd like the array to be [13, 23, 33]. In the example here we have only 3 "xyz" lists, in my actual code I have arbitrarily many "xyz" lists.

I intend to consolidate all the xyz fields to a list of lists before extracting the 3rd component of every list; however, I could only manage to get to half of that before I got confused as to how to proceed. This is what I have tried before getting stuck:

```
for m in tqdm(db.materials.find({structure: {$exists: true}}, {"structure.sites.xyz":1})):
try:
  struc = m[structure]
  site = struc[sites]
  coord = site[xyz]
```

I reached a bottleneck here after trying to obtain a list of every xyz.
The error given is:

```
coord = site["xyz"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm confused as to how the list indices become strings instead of integers when I have not specified the indices in any way. Also, if I need to specify the indices specifically, how should I do it do accommodate the arbitrary number of "xyz" lists I have in the document?

Another question I'm wondering is how to extract the 3rd element of each "xyz" list into an array, although I've not gotten to that part yet.

I understand that there is limited attempt shown here, but this is genuinely all that I can manage before going blank on what to do next. Any instruction, as well as the logic behind it, is greatly appreciated.

Best
Yaze

Comment: Please post the output of `db.materials.find({structure: {$exists: true}}, {"structure.sites.xyz":1})`

Comment: Hi Suraj, the output is as follows:
{"_id":ObjectId("something"), "structure":{"sites":[{"xyz":[11,12,13]}, {"xyz":[21,22,23]}, {"xyz":[31,32,33]}]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sites` value is a list of dict's, not a dict itself, you will need to filter or iterate that list to access each dict.

Also be wary that if the sites list contains any sites *in addition to* "xyz", such as

```
"structure":{"sites":[{"xyz":[1, 2, 3]}, {"z":[4, 5, 6]}, {"x":[7, 8, 9]}]}}
```

your projection will cause the returned value to contain:

```
{"sites":[{"xyz":[1, 2, 3]}, {}, {}]}
```

Which just means you need to test to make sure your current object has "xyz" so you don't get a key error.

Here's a quick and dirty:

```py
    conn = MongoClient()
    db = conn["test"]
    result = list()
    for doc in db.materials.find({"structure.sites.xyz":{"$exists":1,_id:0}},{"structure.sites.xyz":1}):
      struct = doc["structure"]
      sites = struct["sites"]
      dsites = list()
      for s in sites:
        if s.has_key("xyz"):
           dsites.append(s["xyz"][2])
      result.append(dsites)

    print result
```

With the input collection containing 4 documents:

```
{"structure":{"sites":[{"xyz":[11, 12, 13 ]}, {"xyz":[21, 22, 23 ]}, {"xyz":[31, 32, 33 ]}]}}
{"structure":{"sites":[{"xyz":[1, 2, 3 ]}, {"xyz":[4, 5, 6 ]}, {"xyz":[7, 8, 9 ]}]}}
{"structure":{"sites":[{"z":[1, 2, 3 ]}, {"y":[4, 5, 6 ]}, {"x":[7, 8, 9 ]}]}}
{"structure":{"sites":[{"xyz":[1, 2, 3 ]}, {"z":[4, 5, 6 ]}, {"x":[7, 8, 9 ]}]}
```

This produces:

```
[[13.0, 23.0, 33.0], 
 [3.0, 6.0, 9.0], 
 [3.0]]
```

Comment: Thanks really a bunch Joe! It works! I didn't think of the has_key and append functions when I was writing my script. Your answer is definitely enlightening.

On the side note though, I've realized while running the new script that the "has_key" function has been replaced by "in" in Python 3. So for any fellow newbie out there reading this, you may want to take note.

All in all, a brilliant answer. Thanks a lot Joe.